# Stop Gmail signature from showing up in GitHub issues when replying by email

Tags: gmail, github

My boss often likes to reply to posts on GitHub by email. Unfortunately, this causes both the automatically-quoted original message and his email signature to appear in the GitHub post, which takes up space and is really annoying, especially when [a one-word reply from him ends up taking up my whole screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpPCg.png).

Besides completely disabling his signature for all messages, what config can he change - either on the Gmail side or the GitHub side - to prevent his signature from appearing on GitHub when he replies to issues by email?

Comment: This is probably something that GitHub needs to implement on their side. But, is he using the old universal signal of "signature below"? In other words `-- `? (That's two dashes and a space alone on a line.)

Comment: Why wouldn't he just delete his signature before sending? I don't see how you could force gmail not to include the signature to certain senders...you either have a signature or you don't. He may have to click "show more" to see his signature/be able to delete.